# How do I make my ASP.NET Core app exposed to external PCs?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app running on my server, and I can access it fine at `https://localhost:5001`, but I wanted to have it so that I can see the app from my laptop.

The IP of the server on my local network is `192.168.1.250`, but `https://192.169.1.250:5001` on my laptop does not display my site.

How do I expose the site to this IP (and through port forwarding out to everyone)?

I have Apache2 installed, so a method to (if this is even possible) connect asp.net into Apache2 would work too.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a web application visible to other computers?

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove yes.

Comment: Https probably won't work because your website doesn't have a ssl certificate I'm assuming?

Comment: I do actually have a cert on the server, but neither https or http would work.

Comment: Did you verify your Apache webserver was working, did you see the Apache test page at one point?

Comment: Apache does work

Comment: So what is the issue? The IP does not correctly map to your web page?

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove Apache does not host my ASP.NET app

Answer (score 0):

Apache webserver does not natively work with ASP, it looks like there is a workaround in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a IIS web server? It would make things easier

Comment: no, IIS runs on windows, Apache runs on gnu/Linux. They are different web servers